# Problemas con categorias en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

no se si alguien le ha pasado esto, resulta que yo en la parte de entradas tenia categorías y ahora no me lo muestra. Si bien en las notas de entradas dice haber categorías[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] lo cierto es que no me aparece la solapa. Alguien sabe que puede ser? y como puedo volver a mostrarlo? Puede ser por algún otro post type que haya creado?

Comment: las podes ver y editar usando `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` ? tal vez algun post type esté influyendo

Comment: si es raro porque ninguno de los post type que use tiene categorias, es muy raro porque ni siquiera en el function agregue algo, los post type fueron creados con toolset. no se si eso influyo en algo.

Comment: el toolset completo hace mucho no lo uso, (suelo usar solo el modulo custom posts) puede ser que el manage categories del toolset haya tomado el control de las categorías?

Comment: Si estoy viendo eso, a ver que puede haber afectado. es rarisimo la verdad.